# How to add a mailing feature on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I am taking over a project and a client wants me to add a mailing feature like a gmail with inbox, sent messages and the user can also reply to emails from outside the system and the people receiving it can also reply. I have basic knowledge on laravel but this is my first time creating a feature like this can anyone give a stepping stone.  This project has a VUE.js as a front end and a laravel as an API

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Step -1: Create a Mail using,

```
php artisan make:mail MailName
```

Check the file MailName.php inside App/Mail/ directory

Step - 2: Create a function to send the email with the requested data.

```
public function sendMail(Request $request){
    $data = [
                'value1'=> $request->value1,
                'value2'=> $request->value2,
                'value3'=> $request->value3
            ];
            
            //You can add any function like storing the values into db.
            if(someconditions){ 
                \Mail::to('emailid@domainname.com')->send(new MailName($data));
                return back()->with('success', 'Email has been sent successfully!'); 
            }
            else
            {
                return back()->with('error', 'Something went wrong!');
            }
}
```

Step - 3: Open the App/Mail/MailName.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Address;
//You can include your model here.

class DeleteResponseMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public $data;

     public function __construct($data)
     {
         $this->data = $data;
     }

     /**
      * Get the message envelope.
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope
      */
     public function envelope()
     {
         return new Envelope(
             from: new Address('fromemail@somedomain.com', 'From Email Name'),
             replyTo: [
    new Address('admin@yourdomain.com', 'Your email name'),
],
         subject: 'Email Subject',
         );
     }

     /**
      * Get the message content definition.
      *
      * @return \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content
      */
     public function content()
     {
         return new Content(
         view: 'emails.mail',
        );
     }

      /**
       * Get the attachments for the message.
       *
       * @return array
      */
     public function attachments()
     {
        return [];
     }
 }
```

Step - 4: Create mail.blade.php under resources/views/emails

```
Hi $data['value1'],

We have received your application. Thanks!
```

Step - 5: Open your .env file and add the email configurations.

```
MAIL_MAILER=enteryourmailerhere (ex.smtp)
MAIL_HOST=enteryourmailhosthere (ex.smtp.gmail.com)
MAIL_PORT=entertheport (ex. 25)
MAIL_USERNAME=emailid@yourdomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=emailpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=""
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="fromemail@yourdomain.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

That's all! It should work.

Comment: If the receiver is on gmail can they reply? and can I receive the reply?

Comment: Check my edited answer. I have changed the MailName.php file envelop() function. The user can reply from Gmail and you can receive it.